# VSTS - Query Effort Column Not Displaying Values

Tags: azure-devops

I am putting together a query on VSTS and want to include the Effort column. I was able to do that but no effort values show up in the column. I do have Effort values entered into tasks. Not sure if it shows a task effort value or gets it from someplace else. Or there is a configuration that hides the values of the column (which would seem reasonable that they would not be selectable - if nothing will be shown).

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the expected behavior.

Actually the **Effort** is a group of the fields, you need to add the specific column of the fields under it to display the corresponding values.

So, just include below columns in the query to display the values:

- `Original Estimate`
- `Remaining Work`
- `Completed Work`

[image]